# Users duplicate on Firestore when I use googleSignIn

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have two ways to register a user in Firebase: through email and through Google Sign In.

I perform the user registration by email as follows:

```js
signUp() {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const db = getFirestore();
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    auth,
    this.createEmail,
    this.createPassword
  ).then(
    (userCredential) => {
      const user = userCredential.user;
      this.$router.push("/");
      addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        email: this.createEmail,
        name: this.createName,
      });
    },
  );
},
```

In other words, in addition to saving the user in Firebase Authentication, I also send their name and email to Firestore. And this is my first question:

- Is it the most effective way to save the username and future data that will still be added to it?

Finally, login by Google is done as follows:

```js
googleSignIn() {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
      this.$router.push("/");
      addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        email: result.user.email,
        name: result.user.displayName,
      });
    })
},
```

Here a problem arises because if a user logs in more than once in Firebase Authentication everything is ok, but in Firebase Firestore a user is created for each new login with Google.

- How do I handle this issue of storing users in Firestore, especially users coming from Google Login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd move the `router.push()` statement below `addDoc()` so I can confirm that the document has been added and then user is redirected to other pages. In case of Google SignIn, you can check if the user is new by accessing the `isNewUser` property by fetching additional information. If true, then add document to Firestore else redirect to dashboard:

```js
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then(async (result) => {
  
  // Check if user is new
  const {isNewUser} = getAdditionalUserInfo(result)

  if (isNewUser) {
    await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
      email: result.user.email,
      name: result.user.displayName,
    });
  }
  this.$router.push("/");
})
```

It might be a good idea to set the document ID as user's Firebase Auth UID instead of using `addDoc()` which generated another random ID so it's easier to write security rules. Try refactoring the code to this:

```js
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then(async (result) => {
  
  // Check if user is new
  const {isNewUser} = getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
  const userId = result.user.uid

  if (isNewUser) {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", userId), {
      email: result.user.email,
      name: result.user.displayName,
    });
  }
  this.$router.push("/");
})
```

Comment: Very good your solution, but it actually looks more effective if I set the document ID as the user's Firebase Auth UID. The question is: how do I do it? I confess that I looked for this in the documentation, but I didn't find it.

Comment: This definitely worked! I really appreciate.

Comment: Hi there can achieve same on the using phone-number sign-in